# Is it possible for me to turn my old phone into a raspberry pi if i download the proper software to it

Tags: software-compatibility

I have a cheap crappy old Alcatel smartphone and I wanted to turn it into a raspberry pi.

Comment: you can remove all of the electronics from inside your phone and insert a Raspberry Pi Zero

Answer (score 3):

Sell the phone and use the cash you get as payment towards a Raspberry Pi.